# generate an unique link in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to generate unique links for guest users.
 
Aim is to save actions what users does, pages that user visited, downloaded files etc.
For some users generates these links, and collect statistics of their activity.

For example site adsress is **mysite.com**
to some user gives url like **mysite.com/?dfgjkhd8979ujfk**
and in datgabase saves all actions that user does visited site by that link

how can i do that?

sorry for bad english :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the FriendlyId gem

http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/

It helps to easily generate permalinks.

Comment: He doesn't want permalinks. He wants unique URLs for each user. Had a quick look at friendly_id and it doesn't seem to provide the functionality @unkm is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use their session ids? They are random, and no 2 users can have the same session_id.

Or just use /user/statistics and show current guest's statistics based on their session.
Each user would see a different page with same url.

Comment: this feature needs not for all users, but for some of them. admin generates a url, and sends to some user. actions of that user need to save. not everyone

Comment: Then I guess you'll need to generate those links and save them in your database. And when you save those you'll get a unique id for each entry.

Comment: Sorry mate, that's a different topic.